# RxJava2 Subject with no data

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have to listen for some event, which can happen in many places like button clicks, textChanges, activityCallbacks etc.

I'm using `Subject` to trigger this event. But I dont wan't to send any data with this event.

I just need to notify that some event has happened. For that is there a `Subject` with no Type?

Right now I'm creating a `Subject` of `String`

```
     Subject<String> mSubject = PublishSubject.create();
```

and Im triggering it with some empty String

```
  button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    mSubject.onNext("");
                });
```

but that `String` value does not make any sense. I just need to trigger an event without any data, Just like `Completable` completes without any result values.

Is there any way to do this?

I need somthing like `mSubject.trigger()`

Comment: There is no way to 'just trigger' as in Completable with Subject. If you need a object with more meaning, just create a static object of a special class with a name and pass this through. But I think there is something wrong with the usage of the Subject. You may wrap the clickListener on the Button, then you will get a Observable with 'v' as value. Later you can just use this obserable and discard the 'v'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hans commented, you could define an enum that represents an ignorable value:

```
enum ValueLessSignal {
    IGNORE_ME;
}

PublishSubject<ValueLessSignal> subject = PublishSubject.create();

subject.subscribe(ignore -> { System.out.println("Something happened"); })

subject.onNext(ValueLessSignal.IGNORE_ME);
```

You can chose the naming of the enum and its single instance as you see fit.

Comment: Ok, but again Subjects are the ideal solution for this kind of a usecase right?

Comment: Afaik, the RxBinding library features `Observable`s for signalling change events. The cleanest solution would be to `merge()` those `Observable`s and not use `Subject`s. However, you'd have to deal with the heterogeneous element types. If you don't want to bother, the `Subject` example I demonstrated should be good enough.